# HTML Django - Problema em cadastrar e visualizar os fornecedores em seus respectivos usuários

Tags: html, python, django

Boa tarde a todos

Estou criando uma aplicação em Django e estou com dificuldade em mostrar os dados cadastrados na tela somente do usuário cadastrado, assim como quando crio o fornecedor, ele também não salva no usuário logado.

Os usuários são cadastrados pelo admin, os fornecedores são cadastrados ligados aos usuários. quero expor estes dados na tela.

Abaixo meu código

Models:

```
class fornecedorModels(models.Model):
fornecedor = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
cliente = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)  # importar cliente no fornecedor.
tel = models.PositiveBigIntegerField('Telefone', unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
```

Views:

```
def fornecedorViews(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = fornecedorForms()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'cadfornecedor.html', context=context)
else:
    form = fornecedorForms(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        fornecedor = form.save()
        form = fornecedorForms

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'cadfornecedor.html', context=context)

def fornecedorList(request):
fornecedor = fornecedorModels.objects.filter(fornecedor=request.user)
return render(request, 'listarfornecedor.html', {'fornecedor': fornecedor})
```

Não estou sabendo editar o html para tal ação...